# The best practice of CLI solution in go

Tags: go, command-line-interface, readline, libreadline

I want to implement a program that provides interactive-shell like experience with CLI.
I have been trying https://github.com/bobappleyard/readline but it needs users to install `GNU readline` and it causes some bugs in OSX.

Is there any other solution implemented in go without `cgo` so users do not need to install `GNU readline` additionally?

Comment: have you tried opening a text scanner on `os.Stdin`? for simple cases it's enough. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the liner library from [github.com/peterh/liner](https://github.com/peterh/liner) with some success for this.

It is a pure Go package with no dependencies on readline and works on windows/linux/os x.

See the [docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/peterh/liner) for more info.

---

There is also [github.com/chzyer/readline](https://github.com/chzyer/readline) which looks very competent too - but I haven't tried that one. [Docs are here](https://godoc.org/github.com/chzyer/readline).